# PHP VoiceCloud API return ERROR

Tags: php, api, curl, voice

I'm using [VOICECLOUD API](http://v1.voicecloud.com/api.php) for transcription (Voice to Text).
I call the API using CURL.

the result/response is: (-5 could not save file ) with no more details :(

Here is my code:

```
function CallAPI($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    print_r($result); //Always returns:  -5 could not save file 
}

$url = 'http://api.voicecloud.com/api.cgi?action=sendfile&username=MY+USER+NAME&devkey=11xxxx&idtype=username&fileurl=http://www.EXAMPLE.com/app/recordings/test.mp3&filetype=mp3&callerid=18xxxxxxxx';
CallAPI($url);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **API** states that you should pass the parameters by **`GET`**.

So change your `$data` array like

```
$val=http_build_query($data);
$url='http://api.voicecloud.com/api.cgi';
$url.=$val;//Appending the params to the URL
```

and change your **`CALLAPI()`** like

```
function CallAPI($method, $url, $data = false) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);//Commmented
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);//Commented
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    print_r($result);
    curl_close($curl);
}
```

Comment: Tnx, But where did you use the $val then?

Comment: Oops sorry. Edited the answer. Should be `$url.=$val;`

Comment: I include (?) to URL as it was not there. and the API provide this in their examples. I try also with out (?) but no luck.

Comment: You get the same response ? `-5 could not save file ` ?

Comment: Yes, I get the same response.

Comment: I pass the $URL fixed with key=>value pair, to avoid at least the URL confusion.

Comment: The issue was due to .htaccess, the mp3 file was not accessible. By changing the location of the file it works.